# Unable to find image named "xx" on iWatch error

Tags: iphone, watchkit

All images which I have put in storyboard either in group or button for background are not showing on real watch.
The error is coming unable to find image.
If running the app in simulator, the images comes but not on iwatch.

The images targets are checked for iwatch app.
I think it is because the image and image named error, in the app we set the images using imageNamed so it means that we cannot set images in storyboard.

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your images are .png?

Comment: When I started a project with WatchKit, two `.xcassets` files were created. Make sure that the images are stored in the correct one (i.e., in the WatchKit app, not in the extension? Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Hello, I didn't use .xcassets, but yes the images targets are watchitapp only not the extension, but then also, the error comes.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely the result of "loose" image files in the WatchKit app. There have been many reported problems with loose files showing up in the simulator but not on actual hardware. My recommendation is to create an assets catalog in the WatchKit app (not the extension), and configure each image for the correct screen size.

[image]

If you're using a single image for both screen sizes, you can add it to the `2x` slot and leave the `38 mm 2x` and `42 mm 2x` slots empty.

In code, you refer to the image by its name in the assets catalog:

```
[self.interfaceImage setImageNamed:@"PushPin"];
```

I've included more information in my post on [WatchKit Image Tips](http://blog.mikeswanson.com/post/118580394879/watchkit-image-tips).

Comment: Hello, I have not used xcassests, but if we added the images in targets.